# Numpy 2d dataset with xi and yi

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to numpy therefore I have a basic question to ask.
Here is the problem:

- Please create a 2D dataset {(x1; y1), (x2; y2), ... , (x100; y100)}, where each dimension of xi is
  sampled from a standard normal distribution. Define yi = 0 if ||xi||^2 < 1, else yi = 1. The seed should be set to 42

my question is is ||xi|| the norm of xi? if so isnt it just one number? how do i create a set of yi? when I try to print yi only one number comes out.. Thanks for your help.
I know I'm wrong but how can I fix it? how to create this 2d dataset?
here is my code:

```
rNumber = 4
xi=np.random.standard_normal(rNumber)
print(xi)
  if np.linalg.norm(xi)**2 <1:
    yi=0
  else:
    yi=1
print(yi)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this seems like homework, I don't want to spell it out completely, but...

1. Yes, I think `||xi||^2` is just `xi*xi` in this case; so it's a different number of each `xi`.  (At least I can't think of anything else that would make sense, and it's not wrong given the expression, but the expression is just a bit over-elaborate.)
2. Basically, just take out the `if`, leave out the `linalg.norm` (as above) and print the result of

   `y = x*x < 1`

which should be almost there.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this but I just confirmed that ||xi|| is the vector norm and I should find the set of yi with numpy somehow, so I'm still not sure how to do that

Comment: @mmmmhe: That is, as written, if `x` is a vector, ||xi|| is not a vector norm, it is the norm of element xi. The vector norm is written ||x||. You could define all elements of `y` (ie, all the `yi`) to be the same, based on ||x||, which is also fine question. Also, are you sure that `xi` aren't each a vector? If `xi` are vectors and `yi` are scalars then everything else would make sense, and `xi` being vectors is more what people would mean by a 2D data set as well,.